# Autofac Dependency Injection - Data Not Saving to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am trying to implement Dependency Injection with Autofac. I'm trying to add a WebAPI interface to an MVC application. My goal is to create an application that communicates via API while creating an administration panel. I don't get any error message but data is not saved in database. I think it has something to do with the `Register<EFUnitOfWork>` or the `Register<DbContext>` field.

Business Layer -> AutofacBusinessModule

```
 public class AutofacBusinessModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ArticleManager>().As<IArticleService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfArticleDal>().As<IArticleDal>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<CategoryManager>().As<ICategoryService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfCategoryDal>().As<ICategoryDal>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<CommentManager>().As<ICommentService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfCommentDal>().As<ICommentDal>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<RoleManager>().As<IRoleService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfRoleDal>().As<IRoleDal>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfUserDal>().As<IUserDal>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<ATKlogMSSqlContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<EfUnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions()
                {
                    Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
                }).SingleInstance();

        }
    }
```

Business Layer -> Article Manager

```
public class ArticleManager : IArticleService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ArticleManager(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [ValidationAspect(typeof(ArticleAddDtoValidator))]
        public async Task<IResult> Add(ArticleAddDto articleAddDto, string createdByName)
        {
            var mapping = _mapper.Map<Article>(articleAddDto);
            mapping.CreatedByName = createdByName;
            mapping.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            mapping.ModifiedByName = createdByName;
            mapping.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            mapping.Slug = SlugifyHelper.ConvertSlug(articleAddDto.Title);
            mapping.UserId = 1;

            await _unitOfWork.Articles.AddAsync(mapping);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
            return new SuccessResult(String.Format(Messages.Article.ArticleAdded, articleAddDto.Title));
        }

    }
```

DataAccess Layer -> EFUnitOfWork

```
public class EfUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ATKlogMSSqlContext _context;
        private EfArticleDal _efArticleDal;
        private EfCategoryDal _efCategoryDal;
        private EfCommentDal _efCommentDal;
        private EfRoleDal _efRoleDal;
        private EfUserDal _efUserDal;

        public EfUnitOfWork(ATKlogMSSqlContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            await _context.DisposeAsync();
        }

        public IArticleDal Articles => _efArticleDal ?? new EfArticleDal();
        public ICategoryDal Categories => _efCategoryDal ?? new EfCategoryDal();
        public ICommentDal Comments => _efCommentDal ?? new EfCommentDal();
        public IRoleDal Roles => _efRoleDal ?? new EfRoleDal();
        public IUserDal Users => _efUserDal ?? new EfUserDal();

        public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

MVC -> Startup

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ArticleProfile), typeof(CategoryProfile), typeof(CommentProfile), typeof(UserProfile));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseStatusCodePages();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

MVC Layer -> Program

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
                {
                    builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule());
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
```

Comment: Before `await _unitOfWork.Articles.AddAsync(mapping);`, has `mapping` been mapped correctly? If so, this Q is not related to Autofac and should be reworded to indicate DB save issues.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I checked it in debug mode, everything looks normal. I wrote same project before, but this time I included fluent validation, aop and autofac. The previous one now works well. But this project does not save the data to the database. I think the reason is probably Dependency Resolver. I'm not sure if I did the register operation wrong, it doesn't give an error but it doesn't save either. Queries are same for both